# STL map initialization

Tags: c++

I get this error when I try to compile my program. It has to do with the way I'm constructing the map, but I really can't see something wrong:

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant 
map <int , vector <int> >  radixM (10 , vector <int> (100));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ Yes, use an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map).

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax would be:

```
map <int , vector <int> >  radixM={ {10 , vector <int> (100) }};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
map <int , vector <int> >  radixM = {{10, vector<int>(100)}};
```

If you need to construct it with more elements, you can do it like this:

```
map <int , vector <int> >  radixM = {
    {10, vector<int>(100)},
    {20, vector<int>(200)}
};
```